# Mysql query where column is white space?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, whitespace

This seems like a simple question.  I want to query the MySQL data base where a column is null, "", or white space.  The way I do it now is like this:

```
select * from table where column_1 is null or REPLACE(column_1," ","") = "";
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current method will not show NULLs because of [three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

```
select * from table where column_1 IS NULL OR TRIM(column_1) = '';
```

or

```
select * from table where COALESCE(TRIM(column_1), '') = '';
```

Comment: yes oops sorry forgot that in this post, YES!  the TRIM function, that is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from table where column_1 is null or column_1 = '';
```